# Show data from mysql table in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu where it will display data from mysql table. However I'm having problem as shown below:

I'm doing it this way in my php script

```
<label class="col-form-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">Pilih Subjek</label>
<div class="drop-down-wrapper">
   <?php
   $sql = " SELECT * FROM subjek_ambil WHERE userid='$userid' ";
   $verifikasi = $conn->query($sql);
   $hitung = $verifikasi->num_rows;

   if($hitung){
   while($cetak=$verifikasi->fetch_assoc()){
   extract($cetak);
   echo ' 
    <select name="kod_s" required="true" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="selectsubject">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="'.$subjek1.'">     '.$subjek1.'    </option>
              <option value="'.$subjek2.'">     '.$subjek2.'    </option>
              <option value="'.$subjek3.'">     '.$subjek3.'    </option>
              <option value="'.$subjek4.'">     '.$subjek4.'    </option>
              <option value="'.$subjek5.'">     '.$subjek5.'    </option>
              <option value="'.$subjek6.'">     '.$subjek6.'    </option>
              <option value="'.$subjek7.'">     '.$subjek7.'    </option>
              <option value="'.$subjek8.'">     '.$subjek8.'    </option>
              <option value="'.$subjek9.'">     '.$subjek9.'    </option>
              <option value="'.$subjek10.'">    '.$subjek10.'   </option>
    </select>
            ';
            }

          }
        else{
        echo "";
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

this is my database table for subjek_ambil 
[image: Database Table for subjek_ambil.jpg]

this is the output -
[image: what is shown at the interface.jpg]

My question is,

1) how to only show `<option>` that is not empty ?

2) how to pass the value obtain from the dropdown select and show tables of data that is dynamically derived from the value passed.

I mean, if I choose `LA1 : Asas Perisian Komputer`as the value from dropdown menu, a table with query `$sql="SELECT * FROM fail WHERE kod_s = 'LA 1 : Asas Perisian Komputer' ORDER BY id_f DESC";` is shown.

I want the `kod_s = 'LA 1 : Asas Perisian Komputer'` changes dynamically on user selection.

Comment: About changing dynamically, check this article. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Having a table that has rows with all the same things - Subjects - is really bad design. If I select anyone of those entries - what is meant to happen? What are they related too?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw its a table for subjects taken by student. some students might take 5 subjects, some other might take more subjects or less. From that table, I will call it in a dropdown menu. The can choose the subjects, and a table will show data about that subject.

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi Alright mate, will try to check that out. Thank you!

Comment: @nurzamf - you need to learn about relational databases... They are not spreadsheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use `extract()`? Instead use a foreach loop, checking each value for emptyness with `empty()`.

```
while($cetak=$verifikasi->fetch_assoc()){
  echo '<select name="kod_s" required="true" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="selectsubject">';
  foreach($cetak as $val){
    if(!empty($val)){
      echo "<option value='$val'>$val</option>";
    }
  }
  echo '</select>';
}
```

You could also change the SQL query with `... WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL;`, but impractical due to a bad database structure. Read on the design patterns where you can join tables on id.

Comment: Thank you it helps! but now it shows all data from `id_sa` until the last column which is `userid` . How can I only show the `subjek1, subjek2, subjek3, subjek4, ...... subjek10` only in the dropdown menu list ? I dont want to include the `id_sa` and `userid` .

Comment: Then only select the columns in your sql query you want to display: `SELECT subjek1, subjek2, subjek3, etc FROM subjek_ambil WHERE userid='$userid'`

Comment: Ahhh silly me. Thank you mate! You've been very helpful.